# Edit columns in a text file

Tags: python, format, readline

I have a text file containing 4 columns. I need to remove the first two columns and replace them with one column. The value which I should put as the new column is being produced in a loop. Here is something I am trying to do.

The input is like this:

```
   1 2 3 4
   5 6 7 8
   9 1 2 3
```

The output should be like this:

```
d 3 4
d 7 8
d 2 3
```

but "d" is a variable that is being produced in a loop for each line.

```
with open('EQ.txt','r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f
...
...
d=r+d
with open(c.txt, "w") as wrt:
new_line = d\n.format(line[2], line[3])
wrt.write(new_line)
```

Comment: `d=r+d` - what is `r` ?

Comment: What is `d\n.format` supposed to mean? Did you forget to put quotes around the format string?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Correct indentation is crucial for parsing Python.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
new_line = "%d %d %d\n".format(d, line[2], line[3])
```

The format string has to be in quotes, with `%d` formats to specify that you want decimal numbers there. Then you list all three values in the argument list.